# How to get the column value prefrence over the other table value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need all the emails from tempfinal and title,first_name  from htc,pea if emails are present.
Not sure the below query is correct as it is taking more time 10 min to run.
Using 'AND' instead of 'OR' gives me only 4 rows which is not correct.Please advise

```
SELECT f.email_address,
       isnull(htc.TITLE, pea.title)           TITLE,
       isnull(htc.FIRST_NAME, pea.FIRST_NAME) FIRST_NAME,
FROM   #tempFinal F,
       htc,
       pea
WHERE  f.EMAIL_ADDRESS = htc.EMAIL_ADDRESS
        OR f.EMAIL_ADDRESS = pea.EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SELECT  F.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
            ISNULL(H.TITLE,P.TITLE) TITLE,
            ISNULL(H.FIRST_NAME,P.FIRST_NAME) FIRST_NAME
    FROM #tempFinal F
    LEFT JOIN htc H
        ON F.EMAIL_ADDRESS = H.EMAIL_ADDRESS
    LEFT JOIN pea P
        ON F.EMAIL_ADDRESS = P.EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

You should stop using implicit joins, instead use explicit ANSI Joins. This will help you avoid accidental cartesians product (wich I guess is your current problem)

Answer (score 0):

I think the or condition in the where clause is basically creating a cross join situation.

Try this:

```
SELECT f.email_address,
       isnull(htc.TITLE, pea.title)           TITLE,
       isnull(htc.FIRST_NAME, pea.FIRST_NAME) FIRST_NAME,
FROM   #tempFinal F
       Left Join htc
        on f.EMAIL_ADDRESS = htc.EMAIL_ADDRESS
       Left Join pea
        on f.EMAIL_ADDRESS = pea.EMAIL_ADDRESS
```